# Most performant way to grab 50 frames from a video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a tiled image using even spread frames from a video. I need it to be as fast as possible and this is what I ended up with. Are there any obvious performance tweaks for ffmpeg I can use to optimize the speed of this command?

```bsh
docker run jrottenberg/ffmpeg \
  -hide_banner \
  -loglevel panic \
  -i "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" \
  -c:a copy \
  -f mjpeg \
  -preset ultrafast \
  -an \
  -c:v mjpeg \
  -vf "select='not(mod(n\\,286))',yadif,scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=480:270,tile=1x50" \
  -q:v 10 \
  -frames:v 1 - > scrub.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your selection interval is 286 frames, you might as well only select keyframes. So, you can skip decoding other frames.

```
docker run jrottenberg/ffmpeg \
  -hide_banner \
  -loglevel panic \
  -skip_frame nokey -i "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" \
  -f mjpeg \
  -vf "yadif,scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=480:270,tile=1x50" \
  -q:v 10 \
  -frames:v 1 - > scrub.jpg
```

Comment: that was a real performance boost. Thank you very much .

Comment: I can see that you left out the select part so the result is not the same. Is it possible to combine skip_frames and select?

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to select the same frames. In order to get the same frames, you have to decode the whole stream which is what you're doing. You can add select with a time-based expression.

Comment: so if I have a video with duration 3.461795 and would like to get 50 frames from that one. Can I use -vf fps= in some kind of way or what is the best way to do time-based selection?

Comment: Maybe something like this would work? But this does not seem to work with short videos that are just a couple of seconds long? https://gist.github.com/marcuslindblom/8a0105a393c22c7fb236d786ef7768a0

Comment: This is what I ended up with https://gist.github.com/marcuslindblom/6ccf32aa6309f7df64dbd1b8d71895c6 I think this is the fastest solutuon I tried but DURATION and KEYFRAMES could be optimized into a single call to ffmpeg maybe.